# Traverse a Tree and find a Node

Tags: tree, nodes, graph-theory

[image]

I want to traverse a tree like that and find a given node.

Node Class:

```
    class Node {
    Lion lion;
    Node next, child;

    public Node(Lion lion) {
        this.lion = lion;
        next = child = null;
    }

}
```

Traverse Method:

```
 // Traverses tree in depth first order
    public void traverseTree(Node root) {
        if (root == null)
            return;
        while (root != null) {
            System.out.print(root.lion.getName() + " ");
            if (root.child != null)
                traverseTree(root.child);

            root = root.next;
        }
    }
```

My Search Function:

```
 public Node findNode(Node root,String searchedLionName){


        while (root != null) {
            //System.out.print(root.lion.getName() + " ");
            //System.out.println("Root lion name:" + root.lion.getName() + " Searched lion: "+ lionName);
            if(root.lion.getName().equals(searchedLionName)){
                System.out.println("found lion name: " +root.lion.getName());
                return root;

            }
            if (root.child != null){
                return findNode(root.child,searchedLionName);
            }

            root = root.next;
        }

        return new Node(new Lion("debugTEST",-1));

    }
```

Why my findNode function is not working properly is there any guess about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your node class can "point" to two other nodes ( child and next )

This node at the center of your diagram

[image]

is pointing to three other nodes.  So it cannot be represented correctly by your node class.

You have a big problem!

In the meantime, you can "fix" your search routine by changing

```
return findNode(root.child,searchedLionName);
```

to

```
findNode(root.child,searchedLionName);
```

Comment: Yes, I should add parent attribute I guess. Nevertheless, is there any way to traverse this graph and find specific node?

Comment: I have added traverse method, I can traverse correctly but there is some problem with node finding

Comment: Can you explain why ?

Comment: I have decided to create a new tree structure thanks for your help.